# Changing border colour and removing box shadow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to remove the box shadow and change the border colour:

[image]

I have tried the following CSS code without success:

```
.selector.noshadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

How can I remove it and change the border colour from blue to red? Thanks

edit - HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3" style="background-color:#dcdcdc; padding:1em;">
        <div>
            <label for="createPassword">Create Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputCreatePassword" placeholder="Enter a password" ng-model="createPassword">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, we'll need the HTML of the box too to make sure you're not missing something (a small snippet mind, not the whole page). Ideally - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: Though it's not the best practice, try adding !important after your properties.. Might work to rewrite the default styles.

Comment: I can't see the image so I may not understand the problem, but in any case, here's what I would suggest: if you're on a Windows computer, right-click the element with the unwanted box-shadow and select "Inspect Element" from the context menu. This will open the developer toolkit, and in the right pane, you'll see all of the CSS that's currently affecting the element, and where it comes from. Then you can modify it at the source instead of trying to override it with additional CSS.

Comment: I have added the HTML, sorry about that

Comment: @ScottMcGready You might be looking for [JsFiddle.net](http://JsFiddle.net). ;)

Comment: @Singular1ty just making sure everyone's still paying attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the offending CSS from Bootstrap:

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

You'll need to override those styles like so:

```
#inputCreatePassword:focus {
  border-color: #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change your **border color**:

```
input{
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

And this will remove the **focus**:

```
input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/88z7u4kf/4/

Answer (score 0):

To remove the box shadow :

```
.selector.noshadow {
box-shadow : none;
}
```

To remove the outline(its not border) :

```
#inputCreatePassword {
outline-width : 1px;
outline-color : red;
outline-style : solid;
}
```